# AfipSDK SOAP Argentina Laravel

Tags: laravel, soap

muy buenos días a todos, estoy probando la sdk de Afip para facturar online y me encontré con un pequeño detalle, tengo un listado de ventas realizadas donde el vendedor luego precionará un botón para enviar el total de la facturación al sistema de la afip.

hice pruebas y todo funciona perfecto, pero solo tengo una duda...yo tengo el siguiente código que es el ejemplo que dan con valores predefinidos:

```
public function UploadAfip()
    {
        $data = array(
    'CantReg'       => 1, // Cantidad de comprobantes a registrar
    'PtoVta'        => 1, // Punto de venta
    'CbteTipo'      => 6, // Tipo de comprobante (ver tipos disponibles) 
);

$afip = new Afip(array('CUIT' => 20111111110));

$res = $afip->ElectronicBilling->CreateNextVoucher($data);

$res['CAE']; //CAE asignado el comprobante
$res['CAEFchVto']; //Fecha de vencimiento del CAE (yyyy-mm-dd)
$res['voucher_number']; //Número asignado al comprobante
    }
```

tengo el boton que al precionarlo envia todos los parametros a esta funcion y los reemplaza... pero mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Como hago para por ejemplo (me refiero en el controller)... que si preciono ese botón y los datos se envian a la afip, se guarde en el campo "enviado" un 1 por ejemplo y en caso de que haya un error, lo informe y deje el valor de "enviado" en 0? esto lo haría para habilitar el boton o desactivarlo en caso de que ya haya sido enviado para evitar duplicados.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Deberas guardar $res['CAE'] en base de datos junto al numero de comprobante que acabas de mandar. luego en pantalla, si ese comprobante tiene CAE des